# Can the answer editing page be merged into the question page?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Currently, in the Stack Exchange app, when I click the "add an answer" button, I'm brought to a new page to write/edit my answer. The problem is that, there I can't see the question and hence it's not convenient to review or quote the details of the question. Currently I have to save my edit, go back to the question page and then go to the edit page to re-edit my incomplete answer.

What I'd like to see is that, after I click the button, I can add my answer in a text view at the bottom of the question page, so that I can scroll the page up to see the question and scroll it down to continue editing my answer.

Comment: [It is "Stack Exchange", not "stack exchange"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.